# Qt C++ My Program runs perfectly when using one class, but crashes when I try to run a QThread with the same purpose

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

The program I have written has a function that takes a `QList` and returns the information in said `QList` as a `QString`. This works as intended

I however want to run this function in a thread in order to serialize the process, so I created a new class that runs a `QThread`.

```cpp
//header file

#include "item.h"
#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>
#include <QList>
#include <QString>

class String_Writer_Thread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit String_Writer_Thread(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void run();

    void setList(QList<ITEM*> IList);
signals:
    void EMIT_STRING(QString);
private:
    QList<ITEM*> ITEM_LIST;
};
```

```cpp
//implementation file

#include "string_writer_thread.h"
#include <QMutex>

String_Writer_Thread::String_Writer_Thread(QObject *parent)
    : QThread{parent}
{

}

void String_Writer_Thread::run()
{
    QString XString;
    foreach(auto *I, ITEM_LIST)
    {
        XString.append(I->getString());  
    }
/*getString() is a void function that returns the data from an ITEM item as follows:
Name:  ITEM_NAME            //QString
Size:  ITEM_SIZE            //three int values (height, breadth, length)
Color: ITEM_COLOR           //QString
*/
    emit EMIT_STRING(XString); //should emit the resulting QString
    
    terminate();
    wait();
}

//this function is called before the QThread is started in the main class to insert the QList  
//into the threaded class
void String_Writer_Thread::setList(QList<ITEM*> IList)  
{
    ITEM_LIST.clear();
    foreach(auto I, IList)
    {
        ITEM_LIST.append(I);
    }
}
```

Then in my main class, I initialize an item as such:

```cpp
//main class header

public slots:
    void update_Output(QString String_from_Thread); //handles the emitted string

private:
    String_Writer_Thread *TString;
    QString getThreadString; //this will hold the output from the String_Writer_Thread class

    QList<ITEM*> Item_List;
```

and in the main class' implementation I connect the Signals and Slots as

```cpp
//main class implementations

//initializing TString
    TString = new String_Writer_Thread();

//connecting the signals and slots
    connect(TString, &String_Writer_Thread::EMIT_STRING, this, &MainWindow::update_Output);

...

void MainWindow::update_Output(QString String_from_Thread)
{
    getThreadString = String_from_Thread;
    Text_Output.append(getThreadString); //Text_Output is a QTextEdit in the ui.
                                         //I use it instead of QDebug because QDebug is a pain to 
                                         //work with sometimes
}

void MainWindow::add_Item_to_List(ITEM newI)
{
    Item_List.append(newI);
    TString->setList(Item_List);
    TString->start();
}
```

To compare, the original function is simply

```cpp
QString MainWindow::List_to_String(QList<ITEM*> ITL)
{
    QString XString;
    foreach(auto *I, ITL)
    {
        XString.append(I->getString());  
    }
/*getString() is a void function that returns the data from an ITEM item as follows:
Name:  ITEM_NAME            //QString
Size:  ITEM_SIZE            //three int values (height, breadth, length)
Color: ITEM_COLOR           //QString
*/
    
    return XString;
}
```

Despite the Program building without giving me red or yellow flags, it still crashes.

Comment: "The odd thing is, when I compile the program, I don't get any error reports." - Why do you find that odd? Just because a program *compiles* (is syntactically valid) in *no way* means it is correct, free of [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) or does what you intend. All it means is that the tokens you wrote could be interpreted as C++, doing *something*.

Comment: At what line the code crashes when you run it in debugger? Why do you have that `terminate()` and `wait()`? Where do you instantiate the thread? Is the thread even started (add a break point to it and you will see)?

Comment: Btw. there are many more red-flags which probably do not directly cause the crash but you should get rid of them to write better programs: 1) do not user pre-Qt5 style of `connect` (unless you are stuck in Qt4, of course) 2) do not add items in `setList()` in cycle, you can use direct assignment of the list 3) use meaningful naming conventions for your variables and make your upper/lowercase consistent. This code is absolute mess.

Comment: My guess is that you do not instantiate `String_Writer_Thread *TString;` because you are not showing that part of code, I guess it is missing at all. Since you leave it uninitialized with garbage memory, it probably crashes either when you try to connect its signal or when you call `setList()`. But this you would see immediately if you run the code with debugger.

Comment: *Despite the Program building without giving me red or yellow flags, it still crashes.* -- If it were as easy as getting a program to compile without errors means "no bugs", then there would be no bugs in any existing C++ program ever created, no program would crash, etc.  Ever hear of the stories where a program crashes when it is being demoed to a customer?  How did that happen?  You should also be careful about saying "it compiles OK" -- that in many instances is code words for "I don't want to debug the program, you do it for me".